# Unable click element using stream

Tags: stream

my html like below

Credit Application Link

using below code I wrote code
ListApplinks= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'blockquote')]"));

```
    WebElement apps = Applinks.stream().filter(product-> product.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'a')]"))
        .getText().equals("Credit Application Link")).findFirst().orElse(null);//"//a[contains(text(),'a')]"
    
    apps.click();
}
```

but the result is
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "apps" is null

how to solve this
thanks in advance

how to solve this
thanks in advance